# How do I compare lambda expression to alias property in QueryOver where restriction?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, lambda, queryover

I am trying to write shared layout of queries which share similar restrictions and result set with exception of score property in report. I am passing in score property as lambda expression and I am able to use it in select but Where() is giving me grief.

Any ideas on make Where() work with expression func 
OR how to write Expression acceptable to Where() using another expression func which points to property to be compared?

```
private void SomeMethod(Expression<Func<TDischargeResult, object>> field)       
{
    TBenchmark benchmark = null;

    AnalyticsReport report = null;

    IEnumerable<AnalyticsReport> reports = _session.QueryOver<TDischargeResult>()
        .JoinAlias(record => record.Benchmark, () => benchmark)
        //.Where(field > benchmark.Average) // compare score property to average 
        .SelectList(select =>
        {
            select.SelectAvg(field).WithAlias(() => report.Score);
            return select;
        }).Clone()
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<AnalyticsReport>())
        .List<AnalyticsReport>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an alternate approach:

```
_session.QueryOver<TDischargeResult>()
        .JoinQueryOver(x=>x.Benchmark)
        .Where(x=>field>x.Average)
```

And rest of your code.